# C++ IDE search within specific namespace

Tags: c++, linux, ide

Sometimes there is a huge library and I really cannot find stuffs inside. For example I need too find `func1` nested in heuristic namespaces. Is there any IDE for C++ in Linux environment to help me find such expression?

```
ns1::ns2::ns3::func1
```

Unfortunately many IDEs search based on Regex and cannot distinguish it from `ns4::ns5::ns6::func1` .

```
namespace ns1
{
    namespace ns2
    {

        namespace ns3
        {
            void func1()
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is available an eclipse extension which you can use to develop c/c++ programs. You can download the eclipse IDE and install its cdt(c development tools) extension to start developing c++ applications.

you can also use the [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) for c++ development in linux environment.Qt is a cross-platform application and UI framework for developers using C++ or QML, a CSS & JavaScript like language.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do sublime text or code block have such extensions too?